# Knock Out JS - Hide element when datasource is empty

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an application that uses KO to render the data. Sometimes, the data source for this particular element is non-existent as there was no data available, in this case, I want to hide the div completely. I cannot seem to get this to work. I have this working in another JS file in the same project, in where I check hasOwnProperty() and store as a bool.

```
app.namespace('app.blocks.estimate');

app.blocks.estimate = (function() {
    var blocks = {
        "app.block.estimate": {
            viewModel: function(params) {
                var self = this;

                self.hasData = ko.computed(function() {
                    return this.dataset.data.Total()[0].total() !== null;
                }, app.model.get())

                self.total = ko.observable(app.model.get().dataset.data.Total()[0].total());

                self.gst = ko.observable(numeral(app.model.get().dataset.data.GST()[0].gst()).format('$0,0.00'));

                self.description = ko.observable();

            },
            template: 
            '<!-- ko if: hasData -->' + 
            '<div data-bind="tour: { title: \'Title\', content: \'Content.\', placement: \'left\' }">' +
            '<h1 class="text-right" data-bind="text: total()"></h1>' +
            '<h6 class="text-right">The total includes <b data-bind="text: gst()"></b> of GST.</h6>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<!--/ko-->'
        }
    };

    return {
        init: function() {
            app.blocks.register(blocks);
        }
    };
})(app);

app.blocks.estimate.init();
```

The DOM still shows

```
<!-- ko if: hasData-->
<div class="jumbotron" data-bind="tour: { title: 'Title', content: 'Description', placement: 'left' }">
    <h1 class="text-right" data-bind="text: total()"/>
    <h6 class="text-right">The total includes <b data-bind="text: gst()"/> of GST.</h6>
</div>
<!--/ko-->
```

Even if I change it to the below, it still displays the data.

```
<!-- ko ifnot: hasData -->
```

Comment: When you create a snippet, please make sure it works

Comment: Generally speaking that's the purpose of the "if" binding. What problems did you have getting it to work? Were there errors? What was the behavior?

Comment: No errors that I can see, I've updated the question with some alterations and some further info.